# - The Derivatives not as scalars?

Tags: calculus

Im reading a paper that says switching to a function from a manifold to the real numbers loses some simplicities, such as the derivative cant be represented by scalars. What does that mean? It also says the rate of change of the function is directionally dependent - well the derivative seems to be directionally dependent enough because the negative of the slop is- if I could have specifics, that would be very helpful thanks.

Second page- 
web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~wang.1016/courses/788/Lecs/lec10-brian.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. Consider the $x,y$ Cartesian coordinate plane.
This is a manifold, albeit a very simple one.

Consider the function $f(x,y) = x + 2y$ on this manifold.

People have various ways to describe the derivative of $f$ at the point $(0,0).$
None of those ways can be reduced to a single number that lets you distinguish the derivative of $f(x,y) = x + 2y$ at $(0,0)$ from every other derivative a function can have at that point.
That's what the author means by "can no longer be represented by scalars."

On the real number line, you can go toward the positive end or toward the negative end, but note that in the definition of

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+t) - f(x)}{t},$$

you get the same answer whether $t> 0$ (a small step toward $+\infty$)
or $t < 0$ (a small step toward $-\infty$).
There is an implicit "direction along the real number line" baked right into the definition of the derivative: the positive direction is toward $+\infty$.

(Note that the formula above is slightly different from what was written in the linked paper; this is an error in the paper.)

On the manifold that is the $x,y$ Cartesian plane,
if you travel along the $x$ axis, the function $f(x,y) = x+2y$ increases by $1$ unit for each $1$ unit that $x$ increases, which means it also decreases by $1$ unit for each $1$ unit that $x$ decreases.
But if you go along the $y$ axis, $f(x,y)$ increases by $2$ units for each $1$ unit that $y$ increases.
And if you travel along the line $y = -2x,$ the function $f(x,y)$ doesn't change at all.
And those are only three of the lines through $(0,0)$.
In short, there are many directions you can travel, and many different results you can get by traveling in each direction.

The linked paper gives more specifics about what the derivative of the function on the manifold looks like.
You just need to read a few more lines further.
If you have never studied multiple-variable calculus, however, the extreme amount of new concepts and notations in the next page or so is probably going to be overwhelming.

Comment: Might I ask how come there is no way to distinguish derivatives of functions on a manifold and on $\mathbf{R}$ there is??

Comment: I did not say you cannot distinguish derivatives on a manifold. You can completely describe a derivative. I merely said you cannot do it with _just one number._

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that, because the tangent vector is in a different manifold, there is no scalar multiplication of the local basis in the manifold which can equal it (the derivative).

Comment: In the simple example in my answer, the tangent vector is in the same manifold. It still does not lead to the ability to describe the entire derivative at that point by a single scalar value.